# Study integral convergence of $\int_{1}^\infty (\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{1+x})^{\frac{1}{x}}dx $

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I have to study the convergence of the following integral:

$$\int_{1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{1+x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}dx $$

I tried doing the substitution:
$$u=\frac{1}{x}$$

But couldn't go any further than this

Comment: did you try combining the terms inside the parenthesis? then you can bound that from below and above by a slightly simpler function and then compare the integral with let's say $\int 1/\sqrt x dx$

Comment: This integral does not convergence

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}> \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$
we have :
$$\int^{\infty}_{1} \left({\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}dx $$ diverge